# javascript show hide div

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how to do show and hide div in javascript and simillarly in c# pageload how to call div based on id value.can any one help on this ?

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#cat1">cat1</a></li>
<li><a href="#cat2">cat2</a></li>
<li><a href="#cat3">cat3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="cat1">
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Panel>
<asp:ListView>
</asp:ListView>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<div id="cat2">
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Panel>
<asp:ListView>
</asp:ListView>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<div id="cat3">
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Panel>
<asp:ListView>
</asp:ListView>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you intentionally not wanting to use jQuery?

Comment: @Yuck Your username made that comment!

Comment: If you want to access the div server-side you will need to add `runat="server"` however this will result in the client ID being manipulated if you have master pages because the html control becomes server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference the div in C# codebehind, you will need to add a `runat="server"` attribute to the div.  You can then reference it by ID in the `Page_Load` method.  You should also set `ClientIDMode="Static"` for the div, to fix the ID for the div so that you can reference it in Javascript.  Beware of ID collisions for static IDs.

Using strict Javascript, you can hide the div like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('cat1');
elem.style.display = 'none';
```

And you can show the div like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('cat1');
elem.style.display = 'block';
```

JQuery is probably a better way to go though than the getElementById approach:

```
$('#cat1').hide();
```

and

```
$('#cat1').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function showDiv()
{
  // This is to show the div
   document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideDiv()
{
 // This is to hide the div
   document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The code won't support, if the div has the runat property..

Hope this will help you..